# Sharepoint CSOM Deleting Folder and contents

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

Although this works, it seems rather verbose. Is there a more terse way? Using CSOM and a C# .Net Framework application. Really just want to delete the folder and contents. Thanks.

```
    public static void DeleteFileAndFolder(string file)
    {
        using (var context = Sharepoint.ClientContext)
        {
            context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                Sharepoint.ExtranetUserName,
                Sharepoint.ExtrantPassword);
            var web = context.Web;
            var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(Sharepoint.ListTitle);
            var deleteFile = list.RootFolder.FindFiles(file).Single();
            deleteFile.Context.Load(deleteFile.ListItemAllFields);
            deleteFile.Context.ExecuteQuery();
            var folderUrl = deleteFile.ListItemAllFields["FileDirRef"].ToString();
            var folder = deleteFile.ListItemAllFields.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
            deleteFile.Context.Load(folder);
            deleteFile.Context.ExecuteQuery();
            deleteFile.DeleteObject();
            folder.DeleteObject();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don`t need to get list, you can get folder from web object, see sample to delete files in folder:

```
ClientContext ctx = GetCtx();
Folder rootFolder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativePath(ResourcePath.FromDecodedUrl("your path here"));
ctx.Load(rootFolder, f => f.Files);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var file in rootFolder.Files)
{
    file.DeleteObject();
}
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```